# Mercurial 1.8.3 на Debian Squeeze (6.0)

Tags: mercurial, squeeze, update, debian

Не могли бы подробно расписать, как обновить с 1.6.4 версии на выше упомянутую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [backports](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze-backports/mercurial) для установки (обновления) пакетов, чьи версии в поставке Debian уже устарели. Добавьте

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

в `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sources.list`. Чтобы установить пакет из backports, выполните

```
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install mercurial
```

Comment: помогло, огромное спасибо +)